# How do I delete AWS config using powershell so that I can avoid any charges?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

How exactly do I delete AWS config using powershell?

Ive enabled config and not adding any advanced features such as rules or anything.

I dont see anything in the UI that allows me to delete, and I see that I am starting to incur some charges as part of testing this service.

With other services, I can find either within console or using Powershell module cmdlet a way to delete.

Comment: Are you using the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)?  Every service in there has the ability to delete.  So does the UI.  What are you trying to delete?

Comment: My question clearly states I am targeting accomplishing this powershell? However, I'm more than happy to see how CLI accomplishes this. Im not trying to use UI since I need to script.

Comment: I interpreted powershell as a command line, i.e. cmd.exe the next generation.  It seems you're using the AWS cmdlets instead of the AWS CLI.

Comment: @stdunbar, Correct, the cli and powershell module commandlets are different.

Answer (score 2):

For AWS Config commands in PowerShell see: [AWS Config | AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/ConfigService_cmdlets.html)

The `Stop-CFGConfigurationRecorder` command "stops recording configurations of the AWS resources you have selected to record in your AWS account."

You might also want to run some of the `Remove` commands.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any insight into what Remove cmdlets I would need to run in order to get my account resources to a state they were in BEFORE I setup the Config service? I realize 1 step is to remove the S3 bucket..

Comment: In other words, I want to get back to the screen where it asks me to setup config. Atomic reverse. :)

Comment: No, I don't know all the resources it creates. I guess the goal would be for the Config console to look "empty", so delete whatever is appearing in there.